# Form action downloads ruby script instead of running it

Tags: html, ruby, forms, haml

I'm trying to send an email from a form made in HTML (haml). I've created a script called mailto.rb and I've set it as an action inside the form. The problem is that instead of running the code inside, when I press submit it just downloads the file (mailto.rb).

```
%form{:action => "mailto.rb", :method => "post"}
```

This is the code from the beginning of the form.
In HTML it would be:

```
<form method="post" action="mailto.rb">
```

Also, I've added the path to the ruby executable file on the first line of the ruby file.

```
#!~/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

I know that It would be easier to use rails, but I'm not allowed. I have to use a ruby script.

PS: I'm using Middleman, and I work on localhost.

Comment: Not much information to go on, unfortunately. What webserver technology are you using and how have you integrated HAML?

Comment: I'm using Middleman, and I've worked on localhost, if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is you can't POST request a static file with middleman. Same if you `middleman build` your application and pass everything to nginx/apache2. You'll get a [405 error](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

For example to use your script with nginx you have to install and use `spawn-fcgi` and `fcgiwrap`. Spawn a socket or a port from your ruby file and configure nginx to `fastcgi_pass` to fcgiwrap socket.

To use it with apache2, add your site to `/var/www/html` and put this in vhost:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .rb
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

Symlink `cgid.conf` and `cgid.load` to your mods-enabled folder and restart apache2.
Check error log for other problems, but it should work.

EDIT: In this case I'll choose apache2 over nginx. As a 3rd solution you should consider writing a rack script and pass it to unicorn.